# Передача элементов Hashmap

Tags: java, android, activity, android-bundle

Реализовал метод добавление элементов на listview через `HashMap`. Сделал, чтобы при нажатии на элемент открывалось другое активити, как теперь передать значение содержавшееся в `HashMape` в новую активити?

```
flat = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();      
HashMap<String, Object> hm;

hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
hm.put(id, "S 5");
hm.put(name, " Название1");                 
hm.put(clas, " Класс:");        
hm.put(view, " инф");
hm.put(price, " 500  ");
hm.put(img, R.drawable.kras40_main);

flat.add(hm);                            

hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
hm.put(name, " Название2");
hm.put(clas, " Класс2");
hm.put(img, R.drawable.lebed64_main);

flat.add(hm);
```

Comment: Если один из предложенных ответов решает вашу задачу, то вы можете отметить его "Верным", нажав на "галочку" слева от тела ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Когда создаёте `Intent` для вызова второй `activity`, передавайте нужные данные с помощью метода `putExtra`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ParentActivity.this, ChildActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("hm", hm);
startActivity(intent);
```

В методе `onCreate` второй `activity` принимайте переданные данные:

```
HashMap<String, Object> hm;
if (getIntent().hasExtra("hm")) {
    hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("hm");
}
```

Comment: Ну вот например я передаю переменную `clas`, как в новой активити ее содержимое вывести в `textView`?

Comment: Всё просто: передаёте переменную методом `putExtra`, где первый параметр - ключ, а второй - значение.
Далее в новой `activity` получаете это значение, по указанному ключу (в вашем случае `clas`).

Comment: а как содержимое переменной `clas` отобразить в `textview`?

Comment: Также, как обычно. Методом `setText` и преобразованием переменной `clas` в строку, если она не является строковой. Если вы имеете в виду что-то другое, переформулируйте вопрос так, чтобы он был понятен.

Comment: Ну смотрите у меня в первом `Activity` есть переменная `clas`, которая в первой строке `listView` равна `Класс:`, а во второй строке `listview` равна `Класс2`, при нажатие на определенную строчку `listView` мне надо, чтобы на второй `Actyivity` в `textView` отображалось значение выбраной строчки

Comment: При нажатии на строку `listview` передавайте необходимые данные во вторую `activity`, а во второй уже извлекайте и помещайте в `textview` или куда там ещё надо.

Comment: Так у меня и не получается передать необходимые данные, у меня либо пустая переменная передается либо все имеющиеся в такой виде `{name= Название, price= 500, clas= Класс, img= 2130837573}`

Comment: Если нужно передать только переменную `clas`, то её и передавайте: `intent.putExtra("clas", clas);`.  Если она строковая, то получайте её вот так: `String clas = getIntent().getStringExtra("clas");`

Comment: В этом случае передается пустая переменная, а не значение выбраной строчки `listview`

Comment: Значит вы, скорее всего, что-то не то передаёте.

Answer (score 0):

hashmap можно сделать "статичным" и обращаться к его элементам из любого активити по ключу

```
hashmap.get("key")
```